# How to delay in result of group by

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

how i can get single item at a time (concatMerge) and delay it from result of group.pipe(toArray()). i want each item coming out of group array with delay inside that group item.

```
const people = [
  { name: 'Sue', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Joe', age: 30 },
  { name: 'Frank', age: 25 },
  { name: 'Sarah', age: 35 }
];

from(people).pipe(
  groupBy(person => person.age, p => p.name),
  mergeMap(group => zip(of(group.key), group.pipe(toArray())))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule operations with `setTimeout` command

```
setTimeout (() => {
     console.log("Hello from setTimeout");
  }, 1000);
```

or unsubscribing:

```
// Stop listening for location after 10 seconds
setTimeout(() => { locationsSubscription.unsubscribe(); }, 10000);
```

or subscribe again:

```
// After 1/2 second, subscribe again.
setTimeout(() => {
  sequence.subscribe({
    next(num) { console.log('2nd subscribe: ' + num); },
    complete() { console.log('2nd sequence finished.'); }
  });
}, 500);
```

or delay console.log:

```
setTimeout (() => {
     console.log("Hello from setTimeout");
  }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `delay()

```
from(people).pipe(
  groupBy(person => person.age, p => p.name),
  concatMap(group => zip(of(group.key), group.pipe(toArray())).pipe(delay(2000)))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-groupby-key-vals-s8nsjq?file=index.ts

Comment: why it return empty array ? how i can delay based on time value inside array

Comment: updated the answer, i don't think it make sense to delay base on a dynanmic time value, if it is a continuous stream. Time value will be a constant that map to a key. You can use a separate object to store this relationship.